bluetooth stutters in S0 sleep mode
I have a Vivobook S 14 laptop (M3402RA model) running Win11. I have a problem with it entering S0 low powered idle mode. During this mode my bluetooth starts stuttering making listening to audio unbearable.
Usually if I lock my screen win Win + L, the screen turns off after a minute or two and stutters begin.
I tried different drivers and even changed the PCI-E bluetooth adapter itself, the problem persists. The laptop had Mediatek MT7921 module initially and I changed it to AX210 but nothing changed. Moreover, even if I use a bluetooth-usb dongle it still doesn't work correctly.

I tried adding this to registry and now it says that S0 is not available on my system but the problem remains.
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power]
"PlatformAoAcOverride"=dword:00000000

I've noticed that on clean win10 or win11 install everything works as it should. But right after first updates Windows pulls some driver updates and this starts happening.

I also went to device manager and checked the driver tree that leads to bluetooth and turned off "Turn off this device for power conservation" on every level as well as went to Win11 settings - Devices - USB - dissallow turning off usb devices when screen turns off (I have Windows in another language, so exact naming might be off)



Seems like the problem was with the videodriver that comes from windows update as well as with AMD Adrenaline which is supposed to be legit for my system.
Another problem arises since I need the videodriver to work in order to connect an external monitor. I've downgraded to Basic Videodriver which can't work them.
